# Is doubling the «que» a thing in French?

Tags: grammaire

If I were to translate a sentence like "I only want you to feel comfortable" from what I know I would say «Je ne veux que que tu sois à l'aise". Do French people actually double the «que», does the sentence even make sense, how would I say it to make it feel natural?

Comment: I've heard native speakers use this *"que que"* in oral speech, but it made other native speakers in the room frown and look at them weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sup>As @jlliagre said in their comment I made a mistake in my answer. Corrected.</sup>

---

What you suggest (using *ne...que* followed by a subordinate clause introduced with *que*) is not possible.

You could:
—  Use the restrictive *ne...que* followed by a noun:

- *Je ne veux que ton bien-être.*

— Use an adverb instead of the restrictive *ne...que* and then have a subordinate clause:

- a- *Je veux simplement que tu sois à l'aise.*
- b- *Je veux seulement que tu sois à l'aise.*
  Option b- could be ambiguous since *seulement* could be understood as your not wanting anything else.

— Replace the restrictive *ne...que* with *tout ce que*:

- *Tout ce que je veux c'est que tu sois à l'aise.*
- *Tout ce que je veux c'est ton bien-être.*

Comment: +1 but I would avoid the anglicism *être confortable* and keep the OP *être à l'aise* better translation.

Comment: @jlliagre Quite right. Thanks. (I was focused on the rest and just didn't pay attention - awful!). I'll ping them.

Comment: @Quippy Please see jlliagre's comment.  Of course *confortable* is not acceptable here. Sorry.